# simplexml doesn't read CDATA

Tags: php, xml, cdata

I want to grab data from a xml file from  a remote location which contains CDATA information in all nodes as listed below.
I use the following PHP function to grab such information but it doesn't work and seems not to be able to catch CDATA tags from xml file.
the question is whether  my piece of code is correct or not ? and if it's wrong can you suggest any php code to get requested information?

```
<Items>
      <Item ID="1">
          <Name>Mountain</Name>
          <Properties>
              <Property Code="feature"><![CDATA[<ul><li>sample text</li></ul>]]></Property>
              <Property Code="SystemRequirements"><![CDATA[Windows XP/Windows Vista]]></Property>
              <Property Code="Description" Type="plain"><![CDATA[sample text2]]></Property>
          </Properties>
      </Item>
<Items>
```

and this is my php code :

```
  <?
    function xmlParse($file, $wrapperName, $callback, $limit = NULL) {
        $xml = new XMLReader();
        if (!$xml->open($file)) {
            die("Failed to open input file.");
        }
        $n = 0;
        $x = 0;
        while ($xml->read()) {
            if ($xml->nodeType == XMLReader::ELEMENT && $xml->name == $wrapperName) {
                while ($xml->read() && $xml->name != $wrapperName) {
                    if ($xml->nodeType == XMLReader::ELEMENT) {
                        //$subarray[]=$xml->expand();
                        $doc = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
                        $simplexml = simplexml_import_dom($doc->importNode($xml->expand(), true));
                        $subarray[]=$simplexml;
                    }
                }
                if ($limit == NULL || $x < $limit) {
                    if ($callback($subarray)) {
                        $x++;
                    }
                    unset($subarray);
                }
                $n++;
            }
        }
        $xml->close();
    }

    echo '<pre>';

    function func1($s) {
        print_r($s);
    }

    xmlParse('myfile.xml', 'Item', 'func1', 100);
```

When I print this object by print_r($s); I can't see CDATA in result !.
do you have any idea in order to retrieve CDATA context ?

Comment: Have you seen the information in this Question? [CData in simplexml opened from XMLReader](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10057352/367456) - This might be exactly your case. Actually it *is* your case. And no, you can not trust the output of `print_r` or `var_dump` with simplexmlelement. It is lying to you (reference: http://stackoverflow.com/q/16119597/367456; http://stackoverflow.com/q/3410520/367456)

Answer (score 1):

Treat it like a string

```
$file = "1.xml";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($file);
foreach($xml->Item->Properties->children() as $properties) {
    printf("%s", $properties);
}
```

Output

```
<ul><li>sample text</li></ul>
Windows XP/Windows Vista
sample text2
```

Answer (score 0):

There is allways way to use DOMDocument to open xml files, for example:

```
$xmlFile = new DOMDocument();
$xmlFile->load(myfile.xml);
echo $xmlFile->getElementsByTagName('Property')->item(0)->nodeValue;
```